# How to pass correct parameters

Tags: google-apps-script

I have this error message:
    Cannot find method getRange((class),number). (line 37, file "Reply")

```
// Create a time-driven trigger
//function createTimeTrigger() {
// trigger every 6 hours
//var everyXminutes = ScriptApp.newTrigger("Main")
  //.timeBased()
  //.everyMinutes(15)
  //.create();
//}

function Main() {
  var row = EmailFormConfirmation( 2 );
  row = EmailFormConfirmation( row );
}

function EmailFormConfirmation( number ){

  var row = number;
  var col = 2  // column to find email addresses

  // Main script
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1ssxFwNRi7r4G5cbhlNYXj5Fm9XhbB0B242Pen3ZTmE4");
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var email = sheet.getRange(number, col).getValue();

   while ( email != "" ) {
  var name = sheet.getRange(row,3).getValue() + " " + sheet.getRange(row,4).getValue(); // combines fields for first and last names
    var subject = "PROJECT: REPLY Thank you for RSVPing to " + sheet.getSheetName() + "!"
    var message = "Hello " + name+ ","+'\n'+'\n'+
      subject + '\n';
    MailApp.sendEmail( email, subject, message );

    row += 1;
    return row;
  }
}
```

It seems like the problem is that 'row' is getting passed as a Class? I'm not sure what's going on. But I need to be able to increment in Main() as it is called on a time-driven trigger based on how EmailFormConfirmation runs.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an Apps Script issue but rather a bad program construction...

- Your while loop will never work since you included a return in the loop that forces function exit
- if you move the return it will never end since email value is not updated in the loop >> infinite loop
- `row += 1` will not necessarily increment row as an integer (it could become `row1`), use `row++` instead
- I don't really understand the purpose of your second line in main :`row = EmailFormConfirmation( row );` since the first call to `EmailFormConfirmation` is already incrementing in the loop...

below is a working code (not sure it does what you wanted):

```
function Main() {
  var row = EmailFormConfirmation( 2 );
  Logger.log('row final value='+row);
}

function EmailFormConfirmation(row){

  var col = 2  // column to find email addresses

  // Main script
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var email = sheet.getRange(row, col).getValue();

  while ( email != "" ) {
    var email = sheet.getRange(row, col).getValue();
    var name = sheet.getRange(row,3).getValue() + " " + sheet.getRange(row,4).getValue(); // combines fields for first and last names
    var subject = "PROJECT: REPLY Thank you for RSVPing to " + sheet.getSheetName() + "!"
    var message = "Hello " + name+ ","+'\n'+'\n'+
      subject + '\n';
//    MailApp.sendEmail( email, subject, message );    
    row++;
    Logger.log(row);
  }
  return row;
}
```

Comment: Will the Logger hold a value over time? i.e. I want a placeholder to ensure I don't end up spamming a person's email address. Currently I am writing to a cell in the given spreadsheet. Is that good practice or should I find another way?

Comment: nope ! the logger is not a place to store things... use your spreadsheet by marking the sent rows with a background color for example... or store in scriptProperties...

Comment: how about accepting the answer if you found it helpful ;-) ?

Comment: I would, but I completely reworked the code before your answer. It now works, or more or less

Answer (score 0):

This code below appears to work now.

```
function send(row, sheet, email){
  var name = sheet.getRange(row,3).getValue() + " " + sheet.getRange(row,4).getValue(); // combines fields for first and last names
  var subject = "PROJECT: REPLY Thank you for RSVPing to " + sheet.getSheetName() + "!" // sheet should be manually named based on 
  //var url = 
  var body = "Hello " + name+ ","+'\n'+'\n'+
      subject + '\n';
  MailApp.sendEmail( email, subject, body ); // or { htmlbody: ""}
}

function Main() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1ssxFwNRi7r4G5cbhlNYXj5Fm9XhbB0B242Pen3ZTmE4");  // Id indicated in url
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  if (sheet.getRange(2,9).getValue() == "") {
    var row = 2;
  }
  else {
    var row = sheet.getRange(2,9).getValue() + 2;
  }
  sheet.getRange(1,9).setValue("Emails sent");
  while ( sheet.getRange(row,2).getValue() != "" ) {
    send(row, sheet, sheet.getRange(row,2).getValue());
    row += 1;
    sheet.getRange(2,9).setValue( row - 2 );
  }
}
```

This will save the data needed to run the function at any time without resending to any email address.